# How to check in Azure .pubxml in version control without the password?

Tags: security, azure, version-control, passwords

I'd like to check in my .pubxml-file in my .net project so my colleagues also can deploy from local environment. But I don't want to have the password to the database in plain text on GitHub. I have setup master to be automatically deployed in Azure, but sometimes we want to publish manually.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the .pubxml-files to your `.gitignore`. You should not post them to GitHub for the reason you mentioned.

All of your colleagues will have to get the .pubxml file somehow so they can do the publish. Either you send the file to them, or they connect to the Azure subscription and get it.